# cc.game.restart() carsh when extend sdkbox in cocos2d-js 3.10

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have an issue and need help. Oh, I realize not only every sdkbox facebook but also just install a sdkbox plugin (like facebook, onesignal ...), all are crashed when calling `cc.game.restart()`.

In AppDelegate.cpp:

```
#ifdef SDKBOX_ENABLED
    sc->addRegisterCallback(register_all_PluginFacebookJS);
    sc->addRegisterCallback(register_all_PluginFacebookJS_helper);
#endif
    sc->addRegisterCallback(register_all_SpriteExJS);
    sc->start();
    sc->runScript("script/jsb_boot.js");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same error and I fixed it
in ScriptingCore.cpp with the following code:

```
void ScriptingCore::cleanup()
...

if(iter->first.compare(0,8,"N6sdkbox") != 0){
      free(iter->second->jsclass);
      free(iter->second);
}
```

Comment: for (auto iter = _js_global_type_map.begin(); iter != _js_global_type_map.end(); ++iter)
    {
//        free(iter->second->jsclass);
//        free(iter->second);
        if(iter->first.compare(0,8,"N6sdkbox") != 0){
                  free(iter->second->jsclass);
                  free(iter->second);
            }
    }